# bisect_plane not clearing in python API

Tags: python, bmesh, bisect

Here is my bisect plane command, which does infact produce new verticies along the bisected plane (Blender 2.90):

```
print('Nverts0',len(bm.verts), len([v for v in bm.verts if v.is_valid]))
bmesh.ops.bisect_plane(bm, geom=bm.edges, dist=0.0001, plane_co=point, use_snap_center=False, clear_outer=True, clear_inner=False) 
print('Nverts1',len(bm.verts), len([v for v in bm.verts if v.is_valid]))
```

However, niether the clear_outer nor clear_inner option has an effect on the geometry or on how many vertices are there are (the printouts). And the v.is_valid flags aren't set false either. Why aren't clear_outer and clear_inner working?

Answer (score 2):

**Set the normal**

The default values of cutting plane coordinate and normal are (0, 0, 0).  A zero length normal is invalid and quite likely does nothing.

Test script

Here is a minimal working example of a script, adds a cube, runs the operator with plane coordinate at origin and its normal as the x axis. *Recommend setting up a little script like below when asking questions*

```
import bmesh
import bpy
from bpy import context

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
ob = context.object
me = ob.data
bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh(me)


print('Nverts0',len(bm.verts), len([v for v in bm.verts if v.is_valid]))
bmesh.ops.bisect_plane(
    bm, 
    geom=bm.edges, 
    dist=0.0001, 
    plane_co=(0, 0, 0), 
    plane_no=(1, 0, 0), 
    use_snap_center=False, 
    clear_outer=True, 
    clear_inner=False,
    ) 
print('Nverts1',len(bm.verts), len([v for v in bm.verts if v.is_valid]))
bm.to_mesh(me)
```

Result

```
Nverts0 8 8
Nverts1 12 12
```

Effectively bisecting all x axis aligned edges, creating 4 ngons with 6 verts.  Nothing to clear as faces are not "ripped".

**Input geometry**

For clear to work on a mesh that has faces, we are going to need to add the faces and verts to the geometry input of the operator.  Recommend with `geom` giving all geometry of a region of interest will make all options work as expected.

```
    geom=bm.verts[:] + bm.edges[:] + bm.faces[:],
```

making this change an running again

```
Nverts0 8 8
Nverts1 8 8
```

Has bisected cube, same vert count one less face.  The "outer" is cleared, *ie* all resultant geometry on the input normal's side of cutting plane.

[image]

**Return Dictionary**

Bmesh operators return information in a dictionary.

```
ret = bmesh.ops.foo.bar(blah)
```

in the case of bisect plane it has members "geom_cut" the edges and verts of the cut and "geom".

Some Examples of using bmesh bisect plane operator.

[Python: Bisect mesh into n parts, without separate 'LOOSE'](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/118884/python-bisect-mesh-into-n-parts-without-separate-loose)

[using bisect but still failing](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/69262/using-bisect-but-still-failing)

[Slice up terrain mesh into chunks](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/80460/slice-up-terrain-mesh-into-chunks)

[How to get part of a mesh with Python API, which requires breaking down some faces?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/130807/how-to-get-part-of-a-mesh-with-python-api-which-requires-breaking-down-some-fac/130809)

[Cutting a mesh in half](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5320/cutting-a-mesh-in-half/160106)

[How to extract side-view outline (e.g. top view) of a 3D object to 2D surface?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/121119/how-to-extract-side-view-outline-e-g-top-view-of-a-3d-object-to-2d-surface/121732)

[Transform cylinder to flat plane - cylinder maze map](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/185087/transform-cylinder-to-flat-plane-cylinder-maze-map/185147)