# Fast way to convert <BMVertSeq> to list of bmesh.types.BMVert

Tags: python, bisect

I'm using bmesh.ops.bisect_plane() to slice a geometry to get planar cross sections.
bisect_plane() requires a list of bm.verts, bm.edges and bm.faces as arguments.

Converting them to a list with list() takes longer than the bisect_plane operator itself.
Is there a faster way? Doesn't bm.from_mesh() already load such lists?

```
import bpy
import bmesh
import time
then = time.time()

obj = bpy.context.active_object


layer_height = 0.8
obj_height =  bpy.context.active_object.dimensions[2]
slices = int(obj_height/layer_height)

for i in range(slices):
    bm = bmesh.new()
    bm.from_mesh(obj.data)

    geom = list(bm.verts)+ list(bm.edges) + list(bm.faces)

    bmesh.ops.bisect_plane(bm,
                              dist=0.0001,
                              geom=geom,
                              plane_co=(0, 0, layer_height*i),
                              plane_no=(0, 0, 1),
                              clear_inner=True,
                              clear_outer=True)
                                  
    layer_mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new(str(i))                               
    layer_obj = bpy.data.objects.new(str(i), layer_mesh)
    bpy.data.collections['Collection'].objects.link(layer_obj)   
                                  
    bm.to_mesh(layer_mesh)
    obj.data.update()

print(time.time()-then)
```

Comment: I'm trying to run you script locally, and it's giving me a "NameError, 'mesh' is not defined" from line 32. Is that supposed to be 'layer_mesh.update()'? I just tried fiddling around with it to get it to run, changed it to that and now the script runs with no errors in .0008 seconds, which idk, doesn't seem terrible in terms of performance. Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Ans: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/195516/bisect-plane-not-clearing-in-python-api

Comment: @Jakemoyo Fixed, speed depends on number of slices and faces in base mesh. @X Y I read most of that before, but realize now that my expectations might have been naive. Just wondered why geom couldn't be the whole bmesh.